# what to get workflow id from campaign in Mailchimp to get customer details?

Tags: mailchimp, activecampaign

I need to get workflow id of campaign as we scheduled the drip mails in mailchimp. Each mail is having separate work flow id ,how to get the workflow id of campaign and details about customer mail id,date and time when the mail sent and its status ,which particular drip mail sent from list of all drip mails.

Referred this link : https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/reports/sent-to-reports/

The send_to option in this provides An array of objects, each representing a campaign recipient. we need to get the workflow detail of this campaign like in this campaign which is having set of workflow drip mail .which workflow mail is sent to whom and what time.

Referred this link to use google-docs :
https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-mail-merge-in-google-docs-with-mailchimp--cms-21530

we have already scheduled to send drip mails using mailchimp.Now we just need to track the customer details that which mail sent to which mail id and its time .

Referred this link to use Campaign sending status webhook :
https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/about-webhooks/

But campaign sending status is not providing mail id details it provides sent status alone.

Please suggest if there is any other way to achieve this